# Trouble accessing with Procedure in SQLFiddle

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqlfiddle

I'm building a query in SQLFiddle using SQL Server 2008. This query is a procedure that selects information. I can't post the query itself, but I can post the Syntax surrounding the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BusinessInfo
  @Variable VarChar(10)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT   Info.*
  FROM     Table Info
  WHERE    Info.PersonKey = @Variable
  ORDER BY Info.LastName
END
GO
EXECUTE BusinessInfo '1'
GO
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, as soon as I put create procedure, it returns nothing. I even built the Procedure, said END GO and re-wrote the entire procedure query afterwards and it pulled back nothing, and then I deleted the Procedure and it pulled back the information I was looking for. What am I doing wrong?

If you need a working example, this will work on any Schema in SQLFiddle

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample
AS
BEGIN
SELECT   'Information'
END
GO
EXECUTE Sample
GO
```

Comment: Add semicolon http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1547

Comment: Thank you! It Works! Meanwhile, I tried that earlier and it didn't work. However I also added GO after the semicolon. Why would that affect this so negatively? What exactly would GO do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1) Change to this (default terminator is semicolon): **[SqlFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/3013/1)**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sample
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   'Information'
END;

EXECUTE Sample
```

2) Change query terminator using 4th button to GO and your example will work.
[image]

Your code after selecting GO as terminator

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BusinessInfo
  @Variable VarChar(10)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT   Info.*
  FROM     Table Info
  WHERE    Info.PersonKey = @Variable
  ORDER BY Info.LastName
END
GO

EXECUTE BusinessInfo '1'
GO
```

Based on [documentation](http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html)

> **What's up with that [ ; ] button under each panel?**
>
> This obscure little button determines how the queries in each of the panels get broken up before they are sent off to the database. This button pops open a dropdown that lists different "query terminators." Query terminators are used as a flag to indicate (when present at the end of a line) that the current statement has ended. The terminator does not get sent to the database; instead, it merely idicates how I should parse the text before I execute the query.
>
> Oftentimes, you won't need to touch this button; the main value this feature will have is in defining stored procedures. This is because it is often the case that within a stored procedure's body definition, you might want to end a line with a semicolon (this is often the case). Since my default query terminator is also a semicolon, there is no obvious way for me to see that your stored procedure's semicolon isn't actually the end of the query. Left with the semicolon terminator, I would break up your procedure definition into incorrect parts, and errors would certainly result. Changing the query terminator to something other than a semicolon avoids this problem.

Comment: Thank you! It Works! Meanwhile, I tried that earlier and it didn't work. However I also added GO after the semicolon. Why would that affect this so negatively? What exactly would GO do in this situation?

Comment: @user3654055 Add also empty line between GO and next definition/EXEC

Comment: Once you've defined it, how do you call the procedure? I put `CALL procedurename` in the query panel, and it says that only SELECT statements are allowed.

Comment: @Barmar Good point and frankly I don't know why the behavior has changed. I used to use SQLFiddle but nowadays I am using: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2f0844c2e5a295653435cb7d31c5de6) or [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fzP1ejcq8Rb8axH8gMewdA/0)

Comment: Me, too, mostly because of all the times I tried to use sqlfiddle.com and got one of those "temporary" errors when trying to build the schema. I asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844585/how-to-call-stored-procedure-at-sqlfiddle) and someone answered that it's a known bug now.