# could not be able to build schema in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I have mysql schema

```
 CREATE TABLE foo(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

insert into foo (_id, name) values (1, "Foo A");
insert into foo (_id, name) values (2, "Foo B");

CREATE TABLE bar (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT);

insert into bar (_id, title) values (1, "Bar A");
insert into bar (_id, title) values (2, "Bar B");

CREATE TABLE bridge
(
    foo_id INT NOT NULL,  
    bar_id INT NOT NULL,  
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo(_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
    FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar(_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

at this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0e77f, works good but when I try to insert data in bridge as

```
INSERT INTO bridge (foo_id, bar_id) values (1, 1);
INSERT INTO bridge (foo_id, bar_id) values (2, 1);
```

it says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO bridge (job_id, cate_id) values (1, 1)' at line 9
```

Comment: It works for me:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1af16.

Comment: Add **semicolon** after `CREATE TABLE bridge (..);`

Comment: You need to add a semicolon at the Create Table Bridge. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1af16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add semicolon after `CREATE TABLE bridge(...) ;`:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

insert into foo (_id, name) values (1, "Foo A");
insert into foo (_id, name) values (2, "Foo B");

CREATE TABLE bar (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT);

insert into bar (_id, title) values (1, "Bar A");
insert into bar (_id, title) values (2, "Bar B");

CREATE TABLE bridge
(
    foo_id INT NOT NULL,  
    bar_id INT NOT NULL,  
    FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo(_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
    FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar(_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;  -- HERE

INSERT INTO bridge (foo_id, bar_id) values (1, 1);
INSERT INTO bridge (foo_id, bar_id) values (2, 1);
```

In `SQLFiddle` every statement should end with terminator(`;`). More info in my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32191527/5070879)